# Jtextarea height increase dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am coding in netbeans, my question is whenever I add text in jtextarea dynamically the textarea should increase its height according to the content so that full content is shown and I don't want scrollbar with jtextarea. I have made both the scrollbar off.

```
       int i=0;
      jtextArea.setText("hello");
      while(i<20){
         jtextArea.setText(jtextArea.getText()+"\nhello");
          i++;
      }
```

Comment: did u try setPreferredSize();    ?

Comment: this should work fine as is. The text area automatically increases. What do you see?

Comment: will u please explain how to use it? @Drastislav

Comment: ...and do you have it set in a IDE specific layout manager? that could be your problem.

Comment: @Oliver Watkins: text area increases its size automatically thats true,but I want them without scrollbar and the whole content to be displayed in the jtextarea.I have made the scrollbar off so only the last few lines are getting displayed.

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!  *",urgent."*  Too localized.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour depends on the layout manager you are using. For example a JFrame uses a BorderLayout by default. So you can do something like:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
frame.add(textArea. BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Now the text area will be the width of the frame and will grow as you type until there is no more space on the frame.

> I have made both the scrollbar off

If you don't want to use the scrollpane then don't create scrollpane. Just add the text area directly to the frame.

Comment: is there no option to grow the height of the textarea according to the content added dynamically? as I have given a example above. @camickr

Comment: :Thank you so much. actuall Jtextarea comes with a Jscrollpane by default.I have removed it and now it works fine.

Comment: No a JTextArea doesn't come with a JScrollPane by default. Somewhere in you code you are creating the scrollpane and adding the text area to it.

Comment: In netbeans it comes.

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks